# Fixing/Correcting OS X home folder file permissions

Tags: macos, osx-lion, file-permissions, chmod, chown

Long story short, I managed to muck up the file permissions within my home directory in OS X (Lion).  While I'm familiar enough with linux file permissions and more than comfortable changing them, I am unable to get the right combination of permissions and/or commands to change them appropriately.

Before I continue however, I must mention that I have a slightly different setup to a standard install.  My hard drive is partitioned into two drives, System and User.

My home folder is located at in Users/[username] on the User drive, ie. when both drives are correctly mounted, it is accessible at /Volumes/User/Users/[username].  In /User/, I have a symlink [username] which points to //Volumes/User/Users/[username] and this has worked just as I wanted.

I tried the following two articles found [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2963) and [here](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20013630-263.html) only t myself locked out of my own home directory.  In the meantime I changed them to full global access so that I can use them but I would like to get around to fixing that.

Comment: That CNET post is probably pretty destructive. You lose access (executable flag) to all directories within your home. I bet that guy has never attempted to actually do what he wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure you own your home folder (note: I'm assuming you're running this from your own user account, and that you're an admin):

```
sudo chown -R $USER:staff ~
```

Then, give yourself proper access and nobody else any access (we'll make some exceptions later). Note that this is 2 commands to make sure that execute access gets added to the directories, but not plain files:

```
chmod -R 600 ~
chmod -R u+rwX ~
```

Now, grant read access to others for the directories they're supposed to have access to. If you don't have a sites folder, you can leave that off the second command:

```
chmod og+rX ~
chmod -R og+rX ~/Public ~/Sites
```

Apple likes to have access control entries to keep you from messing with "important" parts of your home folder.  Again, if you don't have Sites you can leave that off (do not leave out Library; it's invisible, but it's there):

```
chmod +a "group:everyone deny delete" ~ ~/Desktop ~/Documents ~/Downloads ~/Library ~/Movies ~/Music ~/Pictures ~/Public ~/Sites
```

Finally, fix your Drop Box:

```
chmod og=wX ~/Public/Drop\ Box
chmod +a "user:$USER allow list,add_file,search,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown,file_inherit,directory_inherit" ~/Public/Drop\ Box
```

Note that this procedure will not properly "fix" the permissions on files inside your various folders, but that doesn't really matter since it gives you full access to them and nobody else can get into the folders anyway...

Comment: Doing what you suggest will break things. You will take away execute permissions from binaries. Dashboard widgets, programs in `~/Applications`, services will all break. Probably quite a bit more.

Comment: I suggest you skip the second code snippet and invert the third, i.e. take away (non-recursively) `go-rwx` for Documents, Music, etc. (those that are created by default).

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Most OS X users don't have a user Applications folder (or a personal binaries folder, or...). I hadn't thought of Services, though. Call it a personality quirk, but I don't like having execute permission enabled on non-executables, and I'd rather have to fix the occasional file that needs it than set it on everything. You can find any actual executables with `find ~ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep executable` and then add execute for them (`chmod u+x /path/to/file`) individually.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: As for whether to remove group+other access to everything and add it selectively, or remove it selectively, I don't think there's a truly right answer: wiping the original permissions destroyed information, and there's no way to get it back. Your approach probably leaves most files closer to their original permissions, but at the risk of giving away access to things that should *not* be readable, like ~/.ssh

Comment: Have you tested that `find` expression on OS X? There's no *executable* in *Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures    Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64    Mach-O bundle i386*. Maybe `find ~ ! -type d -perm -111` would be better? // If the user's home directory is like mine with 30k executable files, he probably should restore from backup...

Comment: Gave this solution a shot.  Generally seems to work, except now I have some weird functionality with drag/drop.  Essentially I can't seem to drag drop anything (files to folders), one item in a container to another, etc.  Furthermore, even in a browser, mouseover doesn't seem to work either.  Might have to revert back to 777 until I can figure this out.

Comment: I managed to sort out the mouseover issue by disabling and the reenabling my bluetooth mouse, god knows what the hell was going on there.  But the drag drop issue still exists.  My default programs for txt files, etc also seem to have been screwed up along the way too.

Comment: Drag & Drop and default programs are both related to launch services; check its preferences (`ls -le ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices*`) and for services that need to be executable (see the `find` command I gave above).  BTW, for some reason the execute permission seems to be set for the preference lock files, so maybe running `chmod u+x ~/Library/Preferences/*.lockfile` would help.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: the grep I gave won't match the listing for the universal container, but it should match the enclosed executables (e.g. "(for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386").

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER:staff ~` yielded `zsh: bad substitution` That's where I stopped.

Answer (score 5):

To Reset file permissions and Access Control Lists (ACLs) of your user's home directory to their default settings do this:

1. Boot into the Recovery mode by holding down the Command and R keys
   during boot.
2. Open the terminal (under the Utilities menu)
3. Type `resetpassword` into the terminal and hit Return.
4. In the Reset Password utility window choose the correct volume, and on the bottom you’ll see an area labeled ‘Reset Home Folder Permissions and ACLs’. Click the Reset button in that area.
5. Close windows, quick OS X Utilities, restart.

Comment: Reset Home Folder Permissions and ACLs -- this option doesn't appear to be available in Monterey

Comment: I wonder whether in Monterey where 'resetpassword' no longer fixes home folder permissions - maybe there's access to the obscure 'diskutil resetUserPermissions' from the recovery mode.

Answer (score 1):

Repair Disk Permissions by opening Disk Utility, selecting the drive, then clicking Repair Disk Permissions

Comment: From within Disk Utility, I select the "User" partition, and I do not have the option to fix permissions (it is disabled).

Comment: Repair Disk Permissions [only fixes permissions on system files](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1452), not user files.

Answer (score 1):

After much effort and searching:

While not perfect, I just used the Get Info window on the home folder. It showed "read/write" for the user,* "read only" for admin, and "no access" for everyone. Looked good enough to me.

I then ran the option in the gear menu to apply to all enclosed items.

Restored access to everything! Less than a minute (on my SSD).

Hallelujah!                                    *standard, not admin

Answer (score 1):

Run this

```
cd $HOME
{ sudo chflags -R nouchg,nouappnd ~ $TMPDIR.. ; \
sudo chown -R $UID:staff ~ $_ ; \
sudo chmod -R -N ~ $_ ; \
sudo chmod -R 755 ~ $_ ; \
sudo chmod 700 Desktop Documents Downloads Dropbox Library Movies Music Pictures Sites $_ ; \
sudo chmod 777 Public ; \
sudo chmod 733 Public/Drop\ Box ; \
} 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you used [Linc's](https://discussions.apple.com/people/Linc%20Davis) standard procedure as a starting point: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5275515?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

MacOs Catalina here on zsh.

On fixing executables, this worked for me.

```bsh
find ~ -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -0 file | \
  grep executable | \
  awk '{ print $1  }' | \
  tr -d ':' | \
  xargs chmod -v a+x
```

This automates @Gordon Davisson's comment suggestion in the approved answer above.

For those getting `sudo chown -R $USER:staff ~ yielded zsh: bad substitution` error. I suspect this is because of bad context with zsh. The shell switches to the super user (root?) and which would yield an invalid `$USER` and `~` result. My lazy fox was to copy/paste the results. If you want a one-liner, this may give desired results by expanding the results before handing off to `sudo`:

```bsh
sudo chown -R $(echo $USER):staff $(echo ~)
```

I tested and no `bad substitution` error was returned.