# OS X what are default ownership and permissions for home directory?

Tags: macos, permissions, home-directory, ownership

In [related questions](https://superuser.com/q/352260/335246) I see instructions on how to set permissions. What is the default OS X permission for one's home directory. How is mine different?  (See snippet):

```
jbenniMac:~ jbenni$ pwd
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/jbenni
jbenniMac:~ jbenni$ ls -l ..
total 0
drwxrwx---@ 101 jbenni  staff  3434 May 14 17:15 jbenni
jbenniMac:~ jbenni$ mkdir test
mkdir: test: Permission denied
jbenniMac:~ jbenni$
```

Clarification for comment:

```
jbenniMac:~ jbenni$ ls -ledO@ /Users/jbenni
drwxr-xr-x+ 13 jbenni  staff  - 442 Mar  9 15:52 /Users/jbenni
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

Having (or appearing to have) two Home folders isn't intentional. Several years and several versions of the OS ago, I did move my home folder to a different volume when I setup an SSD with just system and Apps. [I used the GUI tool in "Users and Groups" (Opt-click on name, select "Advanced Options..." browse to set the home directory).]

The PWD directory (on "Macintosh HD" volume) is the Desktop dir that I actually see in the Finder.

Note: I added a new user and tested it. Although the new account permissions and ownership appeared to match the problem account, Terminal worked on the new account without permission issues.

Comment: Please post the results of `ls -ledO@  /Users/jbenni`

Comment: Can you explain why you have two home folders?

Comment: I revised the question to explain that.  I suspect you've picked up something significant, but I'm still not seeing the problem clearly.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the results of these commands. (This should be the last information needed). `ls -ledO@ "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/jbenni"` and `mount`.

Comment: Great suggestion.  The ACLs look funky to me, but I've no idea how to fix.  Here's the ls output:  drwxr-xr-x@ 101 jbenni  staff  - 3434 May 15 18:22 /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/jbenni
 com.apple.FinderInfo   32 
 com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot   50 
 com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot   50 
 0: group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown
 1: group:everyone deny delete
 2: user:admin allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity

Comment: Here's the mount output:/dev/disk2s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk0s2 on /Volumes/Internal 100g (hfs, local, journaled)
/dev/disk0s4 on /Volumes/Macintosh HD (hfs, local, journaled)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s4 on /Volumes/JBenniMac AltBoot (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
/dev/disk3 on /Volumes/JBenniMac Back2 (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled)

Comment: Also, see additional comment in question, regarding creating new account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ACL on /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/jbenni is the problem. Remove all three entries with this command:

```
chmod -N "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/jbenni"
```

Comment: Brilliant!  And thanks so much.  This fixed the problem with `mkdir` permissions, and even makes sense.  I've never mucked with ACL's, but I read they can be created in the Finder's Get Info panel on permissions.  I must have done that at some point. Great troubleshooting!

Comment: It turned out to be useful to use Finder's Get-Info and the Permissions panel's Gear icon to "Apply to enclosed items...", since subdirectories also had the funky ACLs.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply create another account and go look into that user's home folder to see what the default permissions are.  That's probably your best way of comparing account rights.